# Estimate of integral

Tags: integration, inequality

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are real numbers satisfying
$$a+\frac{k-1}{n}(b-a)\leq x_k\leq a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a),k=1,2,\cdots,n.$$
Show that
$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^bf(x)dx\right|
\leq \frac{1}{n}\int_{a}^b|f'(x)|dx.$$

My idea: make the interal $[a,b]$ into $n$ subinterals 
$$I_k=\left[a+\frac{k-1}{n}(b-a),a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right],k=1,2,\cdots,n,$$
and then deal with integral $$\int_{I_k}f(x)dx,$$
but I do not knwo how to get the integral 
$$\int_{a}^b|f'(x)|dx.$$

Any help or hint will welcome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_0=a,y_k=a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)$,

$$LHS=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)-\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{y_{k-1}}^{y_k}f(x)dx\right|$$
$$=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f(x_k)-\frac{n}{b-a}\int_{y_{k-1}}^{y_k}f(x)dx\right)\right|$$
$$=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f(x_k)-f(\xi_k)\right)\right|
=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\xi_k}^{x_k}f'(x)dx\right|$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\int_{\xi_k}^{x_k}|f'(x)|dx\right|
\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{y_{k-1}}^{y_k}|f'(x)|dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\int_{a}^{b}|f'(x)|dx=RHS.$$
Here we use mean value theorem of integrals：
$$\exists\ \xi_k\in(a,b),\ \text{such that } f(\xi_k)=\frac{n}{b-a}\int_{y_{k-1}}^{y_k}f(x)dx;$$
and Newton-Leibniz formula
$$f(x_k)-f(\xi_k)=\int_{\xi_k}^{x_k}f'(x)dx.$$